# sql insert or update by comparing values

Tags: mysql, sql

lets say I have a table like this with a lot rows:

```
id | a | b | c
```

before every INSERT there should be a check if there is a row with same 'a' and same 'b', if yes don't INSERT but UPDATE 'c' on that row by summing up their c's.

How to realize that in sql?

Comment: have you tried triggers?

Comment: do not use trigger. use **INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE KEY** that will do both if you have a unique index on all rows. I will post a example as answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here a example with *ON DUPLICATE KEY*:

**You must create a unique key on a and b**

ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD UNIQUE KEY  idx_ab (a,b);

**Insert or UPDATE**

```
INSERT INTO my_table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+VALUES(c);
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> select * from my_table;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]> INSERT INTO my_table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(c);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [yourSchema]> select * from my_table;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | a    | b    | c    |
+----+------+------+------+
|  6 |    1 |    2 |    3 |
|  7 |    4 |    5 |    6 |
+----+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]> INSERT INTO my_table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,99) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(c);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]> select * from my_table;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | a    | b    | c    |
+----+------+------+------+
|  6 |    1 |    2 |   99 |
|  7 |    4 |    5 |    6 |
+----+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]>
```

Comment: IF it is oracle then ?

Comment: Nancy Guruswamy - no, only MySQL / MariaDB . i dont know how to do it on ORACLE

Comment: @Nancy Guruswamy - i have add a sample for you in my answer

Comment: @Nancy Guruswamy - i have add a sample with Sum  for you in my answer. i cant see it in my answer use .... **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+VALUES(c);**